# HereMap Premium SDK on React Native android app - Fragment added but not appear - always size 0

Tags: android, react-native, here-api

I'm going to integrate here map premium sdk especially turn-by-turn map on a React Native app. On the official example, here map sdk provides the `Fragment` with all of it's features. I tried to make framelayout and add that libraries fragment in it. It seems all functions are applied without any exceptions but the map view isn't appear with size 0. 
Following is the replacement codes:

```
public class MapView extends FrameLayout {
    private MapFragment m_mapFragment;
    private AppCompatActivity m_activity;
    ...

    public MapView(AppCompatActivity context) {
        super(context);

        m_activity = context;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        this.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    public void init() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = m_activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        m_mapFragment = new MapFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(this.getId(), m_mapFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commitNow();

        View view = m_mapFragment.getView();
        if (view != null) {
            LayoutParams parmas = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            view.setLayoutParams(parmas);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        initMap();
    }

    private void initMap() {
        // Set path of disk cache
        String diskCacheRoot = m_activity.getFilesDir().getPath()
                + File.separator + ".isolated-here-maps";
        // Retrieve intent name from manifest
        String intentName = "";
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = m_activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(m_activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
            intentName = bundle.getString("INTENT_NAME");
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Failed to find intent name, NameNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(diskCacheRoot, intentName);
        if (!success) {
            // Setting the isolated disk cache was not successful, please check if the path is valid and
            // ensure that it does not match the default location
            // (getExternalStorageDirectory()/.here-maps).
            // Also, ensure the provided intent name does not match the default intent name.
        } else {
            if (m_mapFragment != null) {
                /* Initialize the AndroidXMapFragment, results will be given via the called back. */
                m_mapFragment.init(new ApplicationContext(m_activity), new OnEngineInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {

                        if (error == Error.NONE) {
                            m_map = m_mapFragment.getMap();
                            ...
                        } else {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

As I debugged when `init` function is called, the MapView(FrameLayout) has 1080 width as well but `mapFragment` isn't still shown either map nor green color.

Answer (score 0):

In general the map would only show up once the mapFragement init has been successful. I am guessing the same has not been triggered in the code. There is a callback from the init with an Error code if the mapFragement init fails ([documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/dynamic-mapfragment.html))

```
MyOnEngineInitListener onEngineInitListener = new MyOnEngineInitListener();
ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext(this);
mapFragment.init(context, onEngineInitListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in fact I hadn't shown full codes cause by the big size. I just updated the question (just add the `initMap()` function), as you can see already added `m_mapFragment.init` and the listener is working correctly with `Error.NONE`, but just only the problem of blank white screen visually.Do you have any more suggests?

Comment: Some other suggestions would be : a) Replacing MapFragment with AndroidXMapFragment b) double check the FrameLayout height/width in the layout file c) follow the steps in documentation (https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/dynamic-mapfragment.html) to check if using LinearLayout also the same issue is observed